# Ionic 2 - FIleTransfer Download Not Working in Windows 10 App

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I have an Ionic 2 app and I am trying to view a Pdf from windows 10 app. First I am trying to download the file, then use DocumentViewer to open the pdf. On Android it is working fine. But when I create a windows 10 app, I noticed the whole filetransfer.download method is not being called. I am not even getting the errors. Any idea why? This is my code.

```
                  try {
                   var alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
                        title: 'Downloading',
                        subTitle: '',
                        buttons: ['Dismiss']
                    });
                    alert.present();

                        const fileTransfer: TransferObject = this.transfer.create();

                        const url = 'https://www.physics.ncsu.edu/physics_ed/Articles/On-line%20HW%20TPT.pdf';
                        fileTransfer.download(url, this.file.dataDirectory + 'file.pdf').then((entry) => {

                            alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
                                title: 'Download Finished',
                                subTitle: entry.toURL(),
                                buttons: ['Dismiss']
                            });
                            alert.present();


                            const options = {
                                title: 'My PDF'
                            }

                            //OPEN PDF

                        }, (error) => {
                            //ALERT ERROR AGAIN**
                        })

                    } catch (error) {

                       //ALERT ERROR AGAIN
                    }
```

Comment: Where is your platform.ready function who should be wrapped around it? Have you tried setting multiple console.log statements in your code?

Comment: I tried with platform.ready did not work. The problem is, it is not either firing the catch() function either. I am not sure what is happening. I want to read the errors produced

Comment: Remove your try/catch block, and call .catch() on your fileTransfer.download() method. Note: When accessing native plugins, you should ALWAYS wrap your function within a platform.ready() statement.